# MYSQL calculations avoiding Duplicate Values

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL table is

```
 htno     name       fathername       subcode      subject       internals     externals     total    result      tempcr
 12      Mahesh        Rajesh           256         Maths           20            55           75        P           1
 12      Mahesh        Rajesh           257        Science          18            60           78        P           1
 12      Mahesh        Rajesh           256         Maths           20            55           75        P           1
 12      Mahesh        Rajesh           257        Science          18            60           78        P           1
```

Table has duplicate rows

OUTPUT I need is

```
HTNO     TOTAL MARKS SECURED       PERCENTAGE       TOTAL SUBJECTS       SUBJECTS ATTEMPTED      SUBJECTS ABSENT         SUBJECTS PASSED        BACKLOGS
12               153                   76.5%             2                      2                       0                    2                       0
```

OUTPUT I am getting is

```
HTNO     TOTAL MARKS SECURED       PERCENTAGE       TOTAL SUBJECTS       SUBJECTS ATTEMPTED      SUBJECTS ABSENT         SUBJECTS PASSED        BACKLOGS
12               306                   153%              4                      4                       0                    4                       0
```

which is doubling the actual calculations

I want to exclude those duplicate rows in this calculation

please give me some hint

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` and a subselect.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Which Column I should select using DISTINCT sir??

Comment: @user2598438, a field that you do not have to be repeated, unique.

Comment: using SELECT DISTINCT (subject),htno, also getting the same output which is doubled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT htno, 
       SUM(total)               tech, 
       ROUND(SUM(total) / 2, 2) divi, 
       SUM(tempcr)              cred, 
       SUM(tempcr <= 0)         log,
       SUM(tempcr >  0)         pass, 
       SUM(externals >= 0)      atm, 
       SUM(externals <  0)      tot
  FROM 
( 
  SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM Table1 
   WHERE htno = 12
) q
```

Output:

```
| HTNO | TECH | DIVI | CRED | LOG | PASS | ATM | TOT |
------------------------------------------------------
|   12 |  153 | 76.5 |    2 |   0 |    2 |   2 |   0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce5235/3)** demo

Comment: +1 - shame the data is bad enough that it needs this kind of treatment

Comment: Simply denormalized, maybe somewhat Dimensional modeling?

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_BY or DISTINCT:

```
$sum = $db->prepare("
    SELECT htno, 
    SUM(total) AS tech, 
    ROUND(SUM(total)/7.5, 2) AS divi, 
    SUM(tempcr) AS cred, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tempcr <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS log,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tempcr > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pass, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN externals >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS atm, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN externals >= -2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tot 
    FROM btech32r09july2013 
    WHERE htno = :id 
    GROUP_BY subject"
);
```

Comment: using GROUP_BY there is no output, Using GROUP BY I am getting output printed twice in 2 rows and calculations done are maths+maths and science+science subjects